# How to get DELETE FROM [QUERY] to work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I'm kinda new to mssql, I'm used to Oracle. I'm trying to delete a specific row from a subquery but mssql doens't really like subqueries.

Here is the query:

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1) row FROM randomtable) a
WHERE a.row = 1
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

In Oracle I could've get everything in a query because I can use rownum = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there

```
DELETE a
FROM   (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1) row
        FROM   randomtable) a
WHERE  a.row = 1
```

Though I prefer the CTE syntax

```
WITH a
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1) row
         FROM   randomtable)
DELETE FROM a
WHERE  a.row = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify the table alias in what you wanted to delete from.

```
DELETE a FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1) row FROM randomtable) a
WHERE a.row = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the alias `DELETE a FROM ...`